# Integrating CalDav event sources with Outlook in the Calendar application

Tags: calendar, outlook, caldav

My calendar is a conglomerate of different event sources (personal, work, etc). I bring them together using the [CalDav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) standard - on Android using the [DAVdroid](https://www.davdroid.com/) application.

There is however an event source that does not support CalDav natively: Outlook. On PCs, this is easily manageable with a programme like [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/), that serves as a gateway to Outlook, providing a CalDav interface.

I would like to do something similar on Android in order to integrate CalDav event sources with Outlook in the Calendar application. Which method(s) could achieve this goal?

Comment: Tried this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.astonsoft.android.outlooksync

Comment: @beeshyams For some reason, that application requires a Windows licence - I have none. I would rather go with a light weight solution.